# How do asynchronous OR (||) / AND (&&) tests work?

Tags: javascript

**@reworded question** 
I know the `Promise.` methods provide simple ways to solve AND (&& => `Promise.all` ) , OR (|| => `Promise.any`)  or `Promise.race` for tests when you want the first promise that return a result, but I'd like to understand the construction logic and if it is possible to take advantage of ​​asynchronous objects to do these operations in asynchronous functions (something like the assumption below)

Can someone give me a light?

```
const test = (time, response_value) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time, response_value);
});

(async () => {
    //returns the first result that returns true
    console.log( await (test(Math.random()*500, 'one') || test(Math.random()*500, 'two')) );
    
    //returns the last promise if the first returns true
    console.log( await (test(Math.random()*500, parseInt(Math.random()*2)) && test(Math.random()*500, 'two')) );

    //returns the fastest result
    //???
})();
```

Comment: What you are asking is quite unclear. You mention the "promise library" while promises are built-in and native to modern javascript. You say that there are simple ways to resolve these tests, so maybe show those ways in your code example and what you are asking will become more clear? I have a feeling that you are asking about `Promise.race`, `.all`, `.any` and so on, is that what you would like explained?

Comment: @Ma3x Yes, that's right. are the ``Promise.`` methods I'm referring.

Comment: Well then you should have said so right away. Using examples with random values is not really a good way to ask. But luckily others got the same feeling that you meant those and gave you some nice answers. Enjoy.

Comment: @Ma3x I really think I expressed myself badly, and people didn't understand what I wanted. I will put more information.

Comment: @RafaelLucas the question is still not clear. `provide simple ways to solve AND (&& => Promise.all ) , OR (|| => Promise.any) or Promise.race` there logical JavaScript operators `&&` and `||` and `all`, `any` or `race` have nothing in common. `Promise.race/.any/.all` are about resolve states not their resolved values. Not clear what you mean with `it is possible to take advantage of ​​asynchronous objects` the `await` is syntactic sugar for `.then` that makes many things easier.

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying some of the code, you're asking about these cases:

```
await (promiseA || promiseB || promiseC)
// vs
await (promiseA && promiseB)
```

Both of these are almost certainly *not* what you want to do. The first one will start by evaluating `promiseA || promiseB || promiseC`. Promises are objects, and objects are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so the first part of the `||` is enough to satisfy it. So this calculation results in `promiseA` and the code ends up just doing `await promiseA` with some side effects. Only promiseA will be awaited, and only it will contribute to the log statement.

The second one starts by evaluating `promiseA && promiseB`. Promise objects are again truthy, and the `&&` operator means this calculation will result in `promiseB`. So you end up doing `await promiseB`.

What you very likely meant to do is to use `||` and `&&` on the values *inside* the promises, not the promises themselves. To do that, you will need to await all of the promises, and then do a comparison with the resulting values. So for example:

```
const a = await promiseA;
const b = await promiseB;
const c = await promiseC;
console.log(a || b || c);
```

Or to do it in parallel:

```
const [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB, promiseC]);
console.log(a || b || c);
```

Comment: when using ``async + await``, the instructions become synchronous, and the effect of who finishes the job first is lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test stuff you probably shouldn't use random values as this won't give you reproducible results that are easy to understand.

As the other answer already said, Promises are objects so `promiseA || promiseB` and `promiseA && promiseB` work on those objects and not on the values they possibly resolve to.

The `await` in `await (promiseA || promiseB)` and `await (promiseA && promiseB)` is applied on the result of the evaluation of `promiseA || promiseB` (which is `promiseA`) or of `promiseA && promiseB` (which is always `promiseB`)

If you want to work on the values the Promises resolve to you need to move the `await` to the Promises directly:

```js
async function run() {
  console.log(await Promise.resolve(0) || await Promise.resolve(1))
  console.log(await Promise.resolve(0) && await Promise.resolve(1))
}

run();
```

The comment `//returns the faster (but not)` indicate that you look for [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

```js
const test = (time, response_value) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, time, response_value);
});

(async() => {
  console.log(await Promise.race(
    [
      test(300, 'one'),
      test(200, 'two'),
      test(100, 'three')
    ]
  ));
})()
```

The comment `//returns two if the first returns true` indicates you want: `await Promise.resolve(true) && await Promise.resolve('two')`

```js
async function run() {
  console.log(await Promise.resolve(true) && await Promise.resolve('two'))
  console.log(await Promise.resolve(false) && await Promise.resolve('two'))
}

run();
```

Comment: What I don't understand is how routes are built in the ``Promise.race/.any/.all`` methods, and whether the objects can be used in ``async`` functions

Comment: @RafaelLucas `What I don't understand is how routes are built in the ... , and whether the objects can be used in async functions` I don't understand what you mean. `Promise.race/.any/.all` return a `Promise` and can be used with `await Promise.` to get their result in an `async` function.